# Extract JSON response from jquery ajax to html div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I could not retrieve data to jquery div element but i can see ajax response in firebug.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://m.lowes.com/CatalogServices/product/nvalue/v1_0?nValue=4294857975&maxResults=6&showURL=1&rollUpVariants=1&showUrl=true&storeNumber=0595&priceFlag=rangeBalance&showMarketingBullets=1&callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data) {
            var returnedData = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#result').html(returnedData);
        }
    });
})
```

[this is my response.for example my url contains data productCount:64 ,I should extract productCount from ajax success and display it in html div id result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GamGf.png)

Comment: your dataType change to 'json', Can you post also what you getting in your response?

Comment: Why you think the API supports JSONP?

Comment: No, jsonp is correct as it looks like they are using it for cross-domain

Comment: what is your result element ? try .html(data) directly if its an textbox use value instead of html like this https://jsfiddle.net/v02x36fp/1/

Answer (score 6):

When you parse out the JSOn data you use it like so:

```
var parsed_data = JSON.parse(JSON_DATA);
$('#result').html(parsed_data.key);
```

So if your parsed_data is somewhat like:

```
{name:"test",age:12}
```

then you use it like:

```
$('#result').html(parsed_data.name); //it will give you test
```

if you really want to print out the whole data use `JSON.stringify(obj)` like so:

```
$('#result').html(JSON.stringify(parsed_data));
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are returning a json and you are trying to insert ino the div it, into the div you can only insert html code instead json.

Try to inspect the json you are returning and in case you need to insert each element into the div, do it, but don't do for all.

The html() method doesn't know what you want to assign, it only insert an html.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over your json data in `returnData`. You are not able to put json directy into html. You need to convert / parse / iterate it before. So, for example:

```
$.each(returnedData, function (index, value) {
    // do stuff with it, e. g.:
    //  $('#result').html($('#result').html() + value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/m8udusps/

The code here actually works. However it says there is a problem when it is parsing the JSON. You needed to add `crossDomain: true,` to allow it to actually get the results.

Answer (score 0):

Having received a supposed JSON struct like:

```
{
  "Field1": "value1",
  "Field2": "value2"
}
```

This code gets the values of the keys (just first key in this example). Result is an alert message with `Data: value1`:

```
                $.ajax({
                    'url' : './localurl',
                    'type' : 'GET',
                    'success' : function(data) {
                        alert("Data: "+data.Field1);
                    },
                    'error' : function(request,error) {
                        alert("Error in response: "+JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                });
```

In this case `Field1` is the key received and it is directly accesible through `data` variable, so it is not necessary to do the `JSON.parse(data)` (in fact this `JSON.parse` produce an error)